# Frequently writing to WPF Textbox crashes application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, textbox

I have an application with several tabs. One of these tabs is a "Report" tab that acts as an output console. When I first run the application, I read a file and write maybe 2000 lines to the Textbox. This works fine when a tab that is not the "Report" tab is active.

However, should I be viewing the "Report" tab (with the Textbox) whilst it is having a lot of data written to it, the application writes one or two lines of data and then will not respond. The whole application crashes.

The code I am using to update is quite simple:

```
string timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("H:mm:ss");
string output = this.textbox_report_output.Text;
output += timestamp + ": " + message + "\n";
this.textbox_report_output.Text = output;
this.textbox_report_output.ScrollToEnd();
```

I have had very bad performance with WPF's Textbox when putting it under this kind of stress. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: when you know you are going to write a large number of new lines, why not create a batch update method that builds all of the new lines in memory on a separate thread and then push them out to the actual textbox all at once?

Comment: How do you mean acts as an output console?  So you are looping on that entire code block multiple times?

Comment: What exception is thrown when the application crashes? I'd suggest looking at the `AppendText` method.

Answer (score 3):

> *I have had very bad performance with WPF's Textbox when putting it under this kind of stress. Is there anything I can do?*

Yes, you can write WPF properly instead of pretending that it is Windows Forms.

In WPF, we use data binding to update the UI instead of procedural code. I suggest that you have a good read of the [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN to get you started, but it basically goes like this:

Create a `string` property and implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public string Text { get; set; } // Implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface
```

Data bind it to the `TextBox.Text` property:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Text}" />
```

Set the value:

```
Text = "Some value";
```

Use the `Dispatcher` to run the UI updates while you are still executing other code:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)delegate { Text = "Some value"; });
```

Comment: While this is good advice overall (MVVM), I doubt it will solve OP's performance problem. In fact, I think WinForms would have the same problem, as text boxes simply aren't designed to cope with large amounts of text. A better alternative would be to use a control designed for this purpose.

Comment: actually using String.Format instead of + should help performance as well, but probably not enough

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I don't agree. This is not a final volume problem.  Op states it works when that tab is not active during the update.  He is flooding the UI with individual updates.

Comment: @Blam Ok you're right, looks like I misunderstood that part. But I still think that using a control like AvalonEdit is a better choice for handling large amounts of text.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously there is something wrong beyond what I'm about to say but since you are using WPF, there's a *better way* to update the UI than you are using. Instead of pushing the updates like you are doing, you could let the WPF binding system take care of the logistics of updating the UI.

This way, the updates won't flood the UI thread. To do that, either create a DependencyProperty (or implement INotifyProperty changed) and then bind the text box to the property.

That said, if the application is crashing you're probably doing something else wrong. Maybe you're leaking memory and your getting an OutOfMemoryException?! Or perhaps some threading issue?!

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with the other two responses that data binding is the best option for wpf textbox input and output.  But, in some cases you do not have that luxury, especially, when the data you need is on a view and control you are accessing are via remoting and formatting the UI output is important.

If you are setting the Textbox.Text field in the OnTextChanged event (while in Japanese or Chinese and your entry is full width), then there is a high chance that it will crash your system. Try, instead to capture the LostFocus event, then make corrections there.  Then, it us safe to set the value in the Textbox.Text field.  Also, you can intercept the KeyDown event and remove non-numerical keys except the decimal point.